# Does macOS change how redirection works?

Tags: zsh, macos, command-line

Line 32 of my script is

```
rm ~/UniGen/* 2> /dev/null
```

The redirection is because I expect the directory to be empty sometimes and don't need the clutter of it telling me so.  But I am still getting

```
/Users/WGroleau/bin/Genealogy:32: no matches found: /Users/WGroleau/UniGen/*
```

when I run it.  Why?

Comment: You can tell the shell (via `setopt`) what to do when you use a glob-pattern which has no matches. For instance, you can tell zsh to silently pass the glob-pattern unchanged in this case, or to abort with an error message, or to silently remove the pattern from the parameters. It's up to you. I personally prefer to get an error message and deal with the other cases explicitly if I need them.

Comment: When typing commands, I would not suppress the error.  But this script line is just to clean up a directory that is often already empty.  So the message is of no value.

Comment: In this case, I would write the command as `rm ~/UniGen/*(N) 2> /dev/null`, or set in your script _nullglob_ by default, if you want to have this behaviour enabled for all wildcard applications.

Comment: This is not a difference between MacOS and other Unixes, but a difference between zsh and bash. You can use bash on MacOS (it's just not the default login shell any more) and you can run zsh on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get the error message from the shell. The same would occur if you entered the following command.

```
echo ~/UniGen/* 2> /dev/null
```

The zsh shell expands `*` only to find no matching files, then generates an error message stating this. Both your external command `rm` and my builtin command `echo` never execute. Redirection only occurs when either command writes to `stderr`. In this case, the zsh shell writes to `stderr`.

Try the following instead. Here, the zsh shell in included in the redirection.

```
{ rm ~/UniGen/*; } 2> /dev/null
```

FYI: Bash works differently on `rm ~/UniGen/* 2> /dev/null`. When a bash shell expands `*` to find no match, the string `"/Users/WGroleau/UniGen/*"` is passed to the command `rm` command. In this case, `rm` would output the following message message to `stderr`, which would be redirected to `/dev/null`. In other words, the following message would not appear.

```
rm: /Users/WGroleau/UniGen/*: No such file or directory
```

Anyway, including curly brackets `{}` would suppress the error message for both zsh and bash.

Based on a [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/650254) left by user1934428 regarding the `nomatch` option, a bash like behavior could be emulated by using the subshell below.

```
(unsetopt nomatch;rm ~/UniGen/* 2> /dev/null)
```

Here, `"/Users/WGroleau/UniGen/*"` is passed to the command `rm` command.

Comment: Or the `nullglob` option (which works the same as the bash option of the same name) which makes the glob expand to *nothing* if it doesn't match. Then you can use `2>/dev/null` or `rm -f` to suppress rm's own warning about getting zero args :)

Comment: {} was the easiest.  In over three decades as a software engineer (believe it or not), I never saw that usage.  But then 90% of my work was in compiled languages.